# Delphi dll export record

Tags: delphi, dll, record, dllexport

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to export a record from the dll?  If yes then how to go about it?

My record looks like:

```
variables = record
      name : string;
      units : string;
      value : double;
end;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't export types from a DLL. You need an import unit where you declare your record type.

Comment: in that case what if i declare the unit inside my dll,
and i want to use it in my application

Comment: Well, you can declare your types in a separate unit and share that between the library and application. A DLL can't carry any information but function/procedure and variable addresses. You need a unit, i.e. a Delphi binding for your DLL. If you want to use it with non Delphi programs too, you will need bindings for that language too. (e.g. a C header to use it with C)

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using PAnsiChar() or PWideChar() strings. Serialize your record to the string, such as something like this:

```
procedure MyDLLProc(var RecordAsPString : PChar); 
var
  s : string;
begin
  s := format('%s,%s,%f',[variables.name, variables.units,variables.value]);
  StrPCopy(RecordAsPString,s);
end;
```

Comment: thats cool
 but how do i get access to my name and the unit field apart from
searching for the ',' in the RecordAsPString
 is this the only option?

Comment: I doubt that the result would be properly evaluated when calling from other programming languages.